# Getting all users and use them for the recipient in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I'm sending notifications to a user via Django notifications, and I have username regex working on the HTML so anyone posts with @username it will post and the HTML is linkable so click on the @username it will take anyone to the username profile page. Now I am using Django signals to match the username and print out the username. When I'm using two or three @usernames the notification goes to only for one @username other two @username do not get the notifications.

**Models.py**-

```
class post(models.Model):
parent = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics', null=True, blank=True)
video = models.FileField(upload_to='post_videos', null=True, blank=True)
content = models.TextField()
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True)
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

objects = postManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-date_posted', 'title']

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse ('blog-home')

def total_likes(self):
    return self.likes.count()


def post_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args,**kwargs):
    if created and not instance.parent:
        user_regex = r'@(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)'
        m = re.search(user_regex, instance.content)
    if m:
        username = m.group("username")

        notify.send(instance.author, recipient=m, actor=instance.author, verb='tagged you', 
nf_type='tagged_by_one_user')

post_save.connect(post_save_receiver, sender=post)
```

Comment: You are using `django-notifications` app ?

Comment: Yes to send them notifications. It's a good library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check the variable "m" which you are using for the list of users, I think you are getting only one user there.
You can simply do this by sending all user id in *args or **kwargs. then get all users and use them for the recipient.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting only one user. how to send all user_id into *args or *kwargs to get all the users. A sample code will be great.

Comment: I used args and kwargs before